# Software To Create Karnaugh Maps

Tags: software, karnaugh-map

Does anyone know of any (foss) application to create karnaugh maps. I don't need a K-map solver, just to be able create them so I can export them to ms-word.

Answer (score 7):

There is at least a [LaTeX package for Karnaugh maps and Veitch charts](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/karnaugh/). [K-map](http://k-map.sourceforge.net/) on sourceforge looks promising too (though the source included no Makefile). I hope we'll see others listed here!

Comment: +1 Thanks for your contribution. I don't have time to learn tex/latex so this isn't really an option at the moment.

Comment: I installed k-map which is not bad, although sadly lacking an export... Anyway I ended doing them in excel.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for software to simplify logic equations or create logic diagrams from truth tables I would recommend [Logic Friday](http://sontrak.com/downloads.aspx). I think there is an export feature as well.

Comment: looks like a nice program but unfortunately it doesn't do k-maps (as far as I can tell), which is what I want. Im not really bothered with having the app simplify them, I can easily do that my self. + 1 all the same for the suggestion, Thanks

Comment: What are you using the k-maps for if not to simplify Boolean logic equations?

Comment: I was using them for simplifying... but on paper, I just needed  software to create something pretty for a report. Anyway I ended up using excel. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I seen nice program that can pretty draw k-map at [purefractalsolutions.com](http://purefractalsolutions.com/show.php?c=xgk), it's named "Gorgeous Karnaugh". It can generate html reports, that can be printed after, and (but it has some bugs as I can find) can copy k-maps images to windows clipboard. In free version it is some watermarks added to K-Maps images, but I think in your case that is not a problem. In other reasons that soft seems as dynamically developing and I think it grow up more functionality in the nearest future.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the Gorgous Karnaugh was moved to the http://gorgeous-karnaugh.com.
Also, I find the couple of coupon codes to get discount - 'fallexams' and 'springexams'. As written on site, this codes have limited time to be applied, but this codes can be used throughout the year. Apparently, there are lazy guys removes announcements about discounts, and do not change the discount itself. With coupon it seems to be easier to buy than to find serials/cracks, or keygens. My friend saves a few bucks using this small lifehack ;) Maybe someone handy ;)